# python's video module in Raspberry pi

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I'm working on face detection sample on opencv using python2.7 windows, edited it and wanted to run it on my raspberry pi, but when executing it I'm getting this error.

> ImportError No module named video

The error is on this line

```
from video import create_capture
```

Is there any solution or alternative?

Comment: video.py is some utility file in the samples/python2 folder. in the end you won't need it even

Comment: Not sure if you're following any tutorials, but https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-face-recognition-treasure-box/software covers doing opencv with facial recognition on RPi